# Selecting at most n elements in R

Tags: r, subset

It seems like a very simple question, but I can't figure it out.

How can I select at most n elements from a list in R?

```
> x = 1:3
> x[1:5]
[1]  1  2  3 NA NA
```

What I want is that `x[1:5]` return `[1]  1  2  3`.

My attempted solution is

```
x[!is.na(x[1:3])]
```

which still doesn't work, because

```
> x[!is.na(x[1:5])]
[1] 1 2 3            # correct
> x[!is.na(x[1:2])]
[1] 1 2 3            # where's that coming from?
```

Comment: The logical vector is being recycled to match length of `x`. Try `x[which(!is.na(x[1:2]))]`

Comment: Wouldn't `head` work? `head(x, 5)` for example?

Comment: Oh I didn't think of `head`. Of all the suggested methods this is the neatest. Although it will only work for 1:5, not for say, 2:6.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you don't index past the end of the vector, you can do:

```
x[1:(min(5, length(x)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

> `x[!is.na(x[1:2])]`
>      `[1] 1 2 3            # where's that coming from?`

That's coming from **recycling**.
`is.na(X)` returns a logical vector of length equal to its argument `X`.  Since there are no `NA`s this vector is all `TRUE`s. Those values (again, all `TRUE`) are recycled to the length of `x` (the `x` on the outside of the brackets, `x[ . ]`)

As for taking a selection from x, not to exceed the length of x, use `head` and `tail` as @Ananda mentioned in the comments.

```
x <- 1:6
head(x, 4)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
head(x, 20)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

tail(x, 4)
# [1] 3 4 5 6
tail(x, 20)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```